# Restricting two (or more) columns of a CSS grid layout to exactly one specific width

Tags: html, css, width, css-grid

I have a CSS grid layout with a specific template for the columns, for example:

```css
.layout {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: [t1] 40% [t2] 20% [o1] 1fr [o2] 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
}
.layout > div {
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
.layout > div:first-child {
    grid-row: 1/span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="layout">
    <div>Content t1 1</div>
    <div>Content t2 1</div>
    <div>Content o1 1</div>
    <div>Content o2 1</div>
    <div>Content t2 2</div>
    <div>Content o1 2</div>
    <div>Content o2 2</div>
</div>
```

In the example, the sum of `[t1]` and `[t2]` is 60%.

What I want to achieve is that the width of `[t2]` fits its content but is at maximum 20% (e.g., with `fit-content(20%)`) *and* that `[t1]` increases or decreases depending on the width of `[t2]` so that the sum of `[t1]` and `[t2]` is still and always remains by 60%. For example, if `[t2]` is 10%, `[t1]` should be 50%.

The part `[o1] 1fr [o2] 1fr` is flexible and sum up to the rest (40% in this example).

Is there a way *without* JS to achieve this with a CSS Grid layout?

I tried different combinations of `auto`, `minmax`, `fit-content`, and `calc`. They do not solve the problem.

I expect something like `calc(60% - [t2])` but have no hope that there is something similar.

A CSS Flexbox layout is not an option because one cell spans over more than one row.

Comment: if the second part needs to be 40% then use 20% 20% and make the first column 1fr

Comment: Could you explain that in a more detailed example, please?

Comment: If I understand you correctly @TemaniAfif, you propose to set the template to ```grid-template-columns: [t1] 1fr 20% [t2] fit-content(20%) [o1] 1fr [o2] 1fr;``` and span the [t1] column over two cells, right? However, if another ```[o] 1fr``` is added in the template, 1fr would have a different size, right?

Answer (score 0):

I think, these kind of calculations/assumptions are not possible with pure CSS. Im pretty sure you already got the idea yourself, but I would wrap the first two and the last two columns in an extra grid like this:

```
<div class="layout-wrapper">
    <div class="layout">
        <div>Content t1 Content t1 Content t1 Content t1 Content t1 Content t1 Content t1 Content t1</div>
    <div>Content t2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="layout">
      <div>Content o1</div>
      <div>Content o2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.layout-wrapper {
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: 3fr 2fr;
}
.layout {
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: minmax(min-content, auto) minmax(min-content, auto);
}
.layout div {
  border: 1px solid #444444
}
```

I know this i not very elegant and might be complicated to use with programmatic for-loops. However, it will maintain the 60-40 ratio.

### UPDATE:

If wrapping the columns is not an option, you might try is this way with your original example:

```
grid-template-columns: minmax(min-content, 3fr) minmax(min-content, 3fr) 2fr 2fr;
```

Apparently you'll have to accept that o1 and o2 will always be same width.

Comment: Thank you @neropha for your proposal. Splitting the grid is a nice idea. However, I unfortunately have a cell that must span over 2 rows. This would be ugly to achieve with subgrids. However, I also had the thought that it cannot be achieved with pure CSS Grids.

Comment: I see, now I understand the problem with the full column-span of one particular cell.
Could you maybe post a more real-life example with the particular cell in question?

Comment: I extended the example with a second row and formated it as code snippet now.

Comment: I've updated my answer. It makes sense, that you'll need static widths to have flexible widths on the other side...

Comment: Ok, I see. However, I would have to use a ```fr```-value in the first two columns as well? Your proposal is based on the 60:40 ratio with 4 columns. However, the 40% could be splitted to several (equal-sized) columns but where it could be difficult to get a ratio for the first one. I have to think about it.

Comment: No, i think you could just use “auto auto”. I just like numbers 

Answer (score 0):

You approach it the wrong way.

The last 2 columns (o1 + o2) are not 1fr but specifically, 20% as both should have the same width while being a total of 40% width.

The 1 column should occupy the remaining space which requires the width of `auto`.

The last column t2 should be as large as it is which could be done with `min-content`

So the rule should be: `grid-template-columns: min-content auto 20% 20%;`

EDIT: As you said you want a variable amount of "o" columns, you can simply use a CSS variable and combine it with `repeat to calculate the with of the o-columns to equal 40% together:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

section {
  display: grid;
  --o-columns: 2;
  grid-template-columns: auto minmax(min-content, 20%) repeat(var(--o-columns), calc(40% / var(--o-columns)));
}

div {
  border: 2px dashed red;
}
```

```html
<h4>100px width for T2</h4>
<section>
  <div>T1</div>
  <div style="min-width: 100px">T2</div>
  <div>O1</div>
  <div>01</div>
</section>

<h4>30vw width for T2</h4>
<section>
  <div>T1</div>
  <div style="min-widthwidth: 30vw">T2</div>
  <div>O1</div>
  <div>01</div>
</section>

<h4>9em width for T2</h4>
<section>
  <div>T1</div>
  <div style="min-width: 9em">T2</div>
  <div>O1</div>
  <div>01</div>
</section>
```

This however will only work if the `t1` element is smaller then 60% total grid width!

Comment: Thank you, @tacoshy, for your proposal. You are right, in this way, it could be solved. Yet, I hoped letting the [o]-parts flexible (1fr) without concrete dimensions. However, it seems not possible (yet) with pure CSS grids.

Comment: Sorry, @tacoshy, do I interpret that correctly: You set the width of column [t1] to a specific length (<60%). However, [t2] is the flexible part that specifies the width of [t1].

Comment: no the t1 column is as long as you define it while t2 occupies the remaining space (`t2 = 100% - 40% - t1`). I also edited the code to allow a variable amount of o columns. Hwoever if you mean that t2 has a predefined with and t1 should occupy the rest then you could just switch it around...

Comment: Ok, either I do not explained it correctly in my question or you misunderstood something: [t1] should be 60% - [t2] where [t2] depends on its content size and shall be limited to 20%. Your solution works fine if I can fix one of the two columns to a specific size. In this case, however, I just need to subtract the fixed size from 60%.

Comment: I don't get what you mean. `[t1] should be 60% - [t2]. That means that [t1] + [t2] should be together 60%. Limiting the t2 width to 20% is not a task of the grid but for the t2 element itself by using `max-width`. The width `min-content` uses the required size of the element. You do not have to hardcode it. It is hardcoded in the example to simulate different width of content...